# Слова без корня

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Стыдно признаться, но я всегда был уверен, что любое слово, являющееся самостоятельной частью речи, имеет корень, даже если корень состоит из одной буквы. И вот на днях в одной лингвистической передаче услышал, что в слове "вынуть" корня нет вообще. Может ли быть такое? Существуют ли еще какие-то слова, исключая производные служебные части речи, где нет корня?

Comment: К слову, в северных русских говорах (напр., в Ахангельской обл.) и доныне употребляется форма "вынять"=))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ОФИЦИАЛЬНЫЙ ВЗГЛЯД: Энциклопедия Русский язык под ред. Ю.Н.Караулова М.: Дрофа, 1997. С.202: "***Слов без корня не бывает**. Единственным исключением является глагол вынуть, в котором выделяется префикс (приставка) ВЫ- (вы-нуть, вы-тащить, вы-нести), суффикс -НУ- (вы-НУ-ть, вы-дер-НУ-ть) и суффикс инфинитива -ТЬ*".

В словаре Тихонова такое деление: вы\ну\ть.

Но есть мнение, что на самом деле корень в слове **вынуть** имеется. Ведь есть однокоренное слово - видовая пара *вынимать* (корень -ним-). Так что в слове **вынуть** приставка ВЫ-, корень -Н-, суффиксы -НУ- и -ТЬ. Происходит интерференция морфов (суффикс -ну- накладывается на корень -н-), в результате на письме вместо -ННУ- получается, что корня якобы нет.

Теперь небольшой экскурс в этимологию. С этимологической точки зрения тут корень -им-, который в позиции перед согласным чередуется с -jа- вследствии того, что праславянское дифтонгическое сочетание *im перед гласными стало сочетанием -им-, а перед согласными превратилось в носовой гласный, обозначавшийся в старославянском юсом малым, которому в современном РЯ соответствует -я-. в старославянском же языке этот корень был свободным, то есть мог употребляться в словах без приставки, поэтому была видовая пара* имати-яти*.
Этот же корень в словах* обнимать-обнять, поднимать-поднять, взимать-взять, снимать-снять, внимать-внять *и т.д.; **-j-** проявляется в смягчении предыдущего согласного.
Согласный -н- появился перед этим корнем тоже по историческим причинам: в праславянскую эпоху приставки этих слов имели вид* obъn, *vъn,* sъn и т.д. В современном языке исконный -н- проявляется только перед -j-. Ср.: *ему - к нему, им (кем?)- с ним, в нём*.
Т.е., с учётом всего вышесказанного, слово должно было бы иметь форму **вынять** с парным по виду глаголом **вынимать**. Думается, что комплекс -ня-, содержащий корень, был попросту формально вытеснен суффиксом -ну- со значением единичного действия (по аналогии со словами вроде *прыгнуть, вдохнуть, втянуть, воспрянуть* и т.п.).
Так что в формальной структуре слова **вынуть** корень действительно выделить нельзя, но он незримо присутствует в его внутренней форме.

Comment: Спасибо, Олечка, необыкновенно интересно.

Comment: Пользуйтесь на здоровье :-)) Была рада помочь. Это хороший вопрос. Ответ не лежит на поверхности.

Comment: Интересный ответ. +1.

В украинском языке **иногда** сохраняются более древние формы некоторых слов (а иногда в русском). Так русс. слово "вынуть" на укр. языке "вийняти". А "вынимать" -- "виймати". Если кому-нибудь это интересно.

Answer (score 5):

Уж столько копий сломано, а воз и ныне там.

В принципе у olsa все изложено верно, но брошу свои пять копеек в версию приверженцев наличия корня.

~1. Ним - не корень, корень "им", "н" - здесь энтетическое, корневое чередование "им" - "я".
~2. "растворение" корня "им" шло по двум направлениям. И - уподобилось предшествующему Ы - и растворилось в нем, М -  ушло в суффикс. Таким образом, две буквы "ы" и "н" можно считать принадлежащими сразу двум морфам. Ы - приставке и корню, Н - корню и суффиксу.
~3. Даже если встать на позицию невозможности деления фонем между морфами, то правильно будет говорить не об отсутствии корня, а о корне нулевой длины, появляющемся в силу чередования "я-им-[0]".

Подробно:

===
Глагол "вынуть" относится к числу немногочисленных русских слов, которые этимологически исходного корня в своём составе не содержат. Однако это не означает, что он, с современной точки зрения, является словом без корня. Непроизводная основа свойственна абсолютно каждому слову и является основным элементом, мотивирующим его значение. Есть корень и в анализируемом глаголе, но это уже другой корень, не совпадающий с тем, который выделялся в нём в момент появления его в языке.

Наш глагол образовался (с помощью приставки вы-) от глагола "яти" - брать, так же как и "взять" (с помощью приставки въз-), "объять" (с помощью приставки объ-), "внять" (с помощью приставки вън-), сравн. эту же приставку в словах "внушить", "внити" - войти и др., "изъять" (с помощью приставки изъ-) и др.

Позднее первоначальное "выяти - выимати" (ср. "выемка") по аналогии с родственным "вняти - внимати", "сняти - снимати" (с приставкой сън-, сравн. ту же приставку в существительном "снедь", родственном словам "еда", "есть" и пр.) получило от них, как и другие глаголы (сравн. "отнять", "принять", "занять", "перенять", "обнять" и пр.), "вставочное" "н" и стало звучать вынять - "вынимать". Затем глагол "вынять" как форма совершенного вида подвергся уже аналогическому воздействию глаголов на -нуть типа "стукнуть", "двинуть", "кинуть" и т.д. и приобрёл в результате этого современное звучание и структуру - "вынуть". Поэтому в нём наблюдается не только процесс переразложения основы, но и явление аппликиции, то есть наложения друг на друга, морфем. Сейчас в глаголе "вынуть" (по соотношению со словами "вынимать", "выемка", "отнимать", "снять" и пр.) непроизводная основа выступает в однозвуковом виде -н-, которое одновременно является и формой выражения суффикса однократности действия (сравн. "вынь", "вынем", "выну" и пр.).

Таким образом, если раньше это слово делилось на вы-н-я-ть (<"выяти" по аналогии с "въняти", "съняти" с заменой -j- на -н-), то сейчас оно делится на морфемы уже следующим образом: вы-н-н-у-ть, то есть приставка вы-, непроизводная основа -н-(чередующаяся с -ним-, -ем-, сравн. "вынимать", "выемка"), суффикс однократного действия -н-, суффикс -у-, выступающий как классовый показатель, подобный -а-, -о-, -е- в словах "звать", "колоть", "тереть", и инфинитивное -ть. Корень -н- и суффикс -н- накладываются друг на друга, все остальные морфемы располагаются в принятой линейной последовательности, одна за другой.

Таким образом, слово "вынуть" и имеет корень, если понимать под ним непроизводную основу как ядро его лексического значения, и не имеет, если понимать под корнем исходный "основный" материал слова. Такой своеобразный и, казалось бы, парадоксальный факт вполне понятен и исторически оправдан.

====
(gramota.ru)

Comment: Спасибо и Вам, мой безымённый! Очень интересно!

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке имеется громадное количество слов, в которых нет корня. Но все эти слова, кроме одного-двух, относятся к служебным частям речи. Напомню, что словом в русском языке принято называть не только "слова-названия", но и все служебные слова. В большинстве из них нет корня. Например: "в", "у", "за", "из", "от", "ишь", "и", "ай". Я перечислила лексические единицы. То есть, слова. А попробуйте отыскать в них корень. Не найдёте. Выше я говорила, что в одном-двух самостоятельных словах (точнее, в словоформах) мы тоже не найдём корня. Я не ошиблась. Мы его не найдём по той причине, кто что он нулевой. То есть, он есть формально (потенциально), но "убежал". Подберите однокоренные слова, и он "прибежит" обратно. Например: "вы - 0 - ну - ть" — "вы - ним - ать". Но есть и мнения, что в последнем примере всё-таки имеется зримый корень, состоящий из "Н", наложенном на суффикс. Лингвисты называют такие явления морфемной интерференцией. Спорный случай.

Источник: [А может так быть, чтобы в слове не было корня? В каком слове нет корня? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/108879-a-mozhet-tak-byt-chtoby-v-slove-ne-bylo-kornja-v-kakom-slove-net-kornja.html#answer5316151).

---

В русском языке, как ни странно, существуют слова без корня. Это глаголы снять, поднять, принять, занять, вынуть, взять, изъять и т. д. Они образованы таким способом: приставка, суффикс -н (встречается не во всех), глагольный суффикс и окончание. Ко всем этим глаголам можно подобрать пару несовершенного вида, которая будет содержать в себе морфему "-им-": поднимать, принимать и т. д. Как ни странно, это корень этих слов. Все они образованы от слова "иметь". То есть, хотя эти слова между собой имеют мало общего, они образованы от одного и того же слова. Также от этих слов образуются существительные или прилагательные, имеющие в своём составе морфему "-ём-" или "-йм-": приём, займ, выемный. Это тот же корень, но здесь происходит чередование.

Источник: [Слова без корня в русском языке | pikabu.ru](https://pikabu.ru/story/slova_bez_kornya_v_russkom_yazyike_5059401).

---

В русском языке слов, у которых не было бы корня, нет. Существует лишь одно исключение – это глагол «вынуть», где «вы-» - это приставка, «ну» - это суффикс, а «ть» - это суффикс, характерный для формы инфинитива.

Но и здесь не все так однозначно. Некоторые языковеды относят этот глагол к тем немногим словам, у которых исходного корня в этимологическом плане просто не существует. Правда, это совсем не показатель того, что в его составе корня нет. Основа, которую именуют непроизводной, присуща всем словам без исключения, и она является тем самым компонентом, который мотивирует значение слова. Если говорить об описываемом глаголе, то его корень не совпадает с корнем, выделяемым в слове на момент возникновения этой лексической единицы в языке.

Характеризуемое слово образовывается от «яти» путем присоединения приставки «вы-». Это слово является аналогом современного «брать». Таким способом образуется немало и других слов, например: «внять» (с приставкой «вън-»), «взять» (с приставкой «въз-»), «изъять» (с приставкой «изъ-»), «объять» (с приставкой «объ»)  и т.д.

Исходная форма глагола «выяти» и «выимати», как и родственные слова «сняти» - «снимати», «вняти» - «внимати» со временем приобрела букву «н», которую можно назвать «вставочной». Следствием этого и стало появление таких форм, как «вынять» и «вынимать».

Позже форма «вынять» (совершенный вид) под влиянием звучания глаголов «кинуть», «сдвинуть», «стукнуть», «сгинуть» и др. получила известную всем форму «вынуть». Здесь речь идет не только о таком явлении, как переразложение, но и о процессе аппликации морфем.

В настоящее время в глаголе «вынуть» (совершенный вид) непроизводной формой основы считается «-н-». Подобный однозвуковой вид является еще и суффиксом, форма выражения которого характеризуется однократностью действия (для сравнения: «вынь», «вынет», «вынут», «вынем»).

В современном русском разбор слова «вынуть» на морфемы будет выглядеть следующим образом: «вы-н-у-ть», где «вы-» - это приставка, «-н-» - это непроизводная форма, которая в других родственных словах чередуется с «-ем-» («выемка»), «-ним-» - («вынимать»), «-н-» - это и суффикс, указывающий на однократность действия, «-у-» - это суффикс, являющийся классовым показателем (аналогично суффиксам «-а-» - «звать», «-е-» - «тереть», «-о-» - «колоть»), «-ть» - элемент инфинитива. Многие лингвисты полагают, что такие морфемы, как корень «-н-» и суффикс «-н-», в этой форме глаголы накладываются друг на друга.

Подытожив все вышесказанное, можно сказать, что с одной стороны, у слова «вынуть» есть корень, если принимать эту морфему за непроизводную форму, которая представляет собой стержень лексического значения слова. Но вместе с тем у этого глагола корня, под которым подразумевают «главный» исходный материал лексической единицы, нет.

Источник: [РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК - ЭТО МЫ | ok.ru](https://ok.ru/russkijyazyketomy/topic/66772529367941).

Answer (score 0):

Я пребываю в полной уверенности, что корень в слове 'вынуть' есть, это -н-. Есть и суффикс одноразового действия -ну-. Просто исторически произошло наложение морфем. И подобных примеров наложения морфем в русском языке не так уж мало. В слове 'разевать' (рот) приставка раз-, корень -зев-, а пишется одна буква з. И здесь наложение морфем. Прилагательные Владимирский, Орловский, Петербургский образовались суффиксом -ск-. А Брянский? Тоже суффиксом -ск-, который наложился на корень. Пишется, таким образом, Брянский, а не Брянскский. Наложение морфем есть и в других словах: рассорить, таксист, пальтовый и т.д. То же явление наложения морфем и в слове 'вынуть'.

Answer (score -1):

Корень в глаголе "вынуть", возможно, есть. Это " нут", которое в иных индо-европейских языках, в частности, в английском пишется как "nut", читается сегодня  как "нат"  и означает "орех, ядро ореха". В русском же языке этот корень также содержится в существительном "нутро", синонимом которого также является "ядро", и в глаголе "кануть" (то есть спрятаться в чём-то, где-то, исчезнуть из вида).
Наличие глагола продлённого действия "вынимать", происходящего от "имать-иметь", естественно, может ставить под сомнение существование корня "нут". Однако имеющие тот же корень глаголы "сунуть, всунуть, кануть" предположить наличие альтернативных корней уже не позволяют.

Comment: А что со словом «вынимать»? У него другой корень?

Comment: Наличие глагола продлённого действия "вынимать", происходящего от "имать-иметь", естественно, может ставить под сомнение существование корня "нут". Однако имеющие тот же корень глаголы "сунуть, всунуть, кануть" предположить наличие альтернативных корней уже не позволяют.